# Passing a completion handler nested into another class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, completionhandler

I am working on a library where using `Swift`. I would like to know is there any better approach I can use in the below scenario,

**ViewController.swift**

```
Movie.searchMovie(name: “AVENGERS”, completionHandler: (Result<[MovieInfo],Error>))
```

The above controller is from sample application where I invoke a public method in Movie Library.

**Movie.swift**

```
public class Movie: NSObject {
        public class func searchMovie(name: String, completionHandler: (Result<[MovieInfo],Error>)) {
          Records.sharedInstance.searchMovieWithName(name: name, completionBlock: { (data, error) in
            guard data != nil  else {
                completionBlock(Result.failure(error ?? “ERROR” as! Error))
            }
            guard let list = data as? [Item] else {
                completionBlock(Result.failure(error ?? "ERROR" as! Error))
            }
            completionBlock(Result.success(list))
        })
        }
}
```

and

**Records.swift**

```
func searchMovieWithName(name: String, completionHandler: (Result<[MovieInfo],Error>)) {
    //Implementation to search
}
```

**Is this how its done? Is there anyway I can do better with completion handlers?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `completionHandler` is not a completion handler:

```
public class func searchMovie(
    name: String, completionHandler: (Result<[MovieInfo],Error>))
```

It is merely a Result object. A handler is a function:

```
public class func searchMovie(
    name: String, completionHandler: (Result<[MovieInfo],Error>) -> Void)
```

Now you have a completion handler that you can call with a Result parameter.